# ruby on rails implement a search form that searches multiple relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I've implemented a simple search form (according to the "simple form" screencast) that searches the "illnesses" table in my DB.
Now I want the same search box to search both the "illnesses" table and the "symptoms" table.

My code currently looks like this:

main_page\index.html.erb:

```
<b>Illnesses</b>
    <%= form_tag illnesses_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %><br/>
        <%= submit_tag "Illnesses", :name => nil %><br/>
      </p>
```

illnesses_controller.rb:

```
class IllnessesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @illnesses = Illness.search(params[:search])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @illnesses }
    end
    ...
end
```

illness.rb:

```
class Illness < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

    def self.search(search)
    if search
        find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
        find(:all)
    end
 end
```

Could you please guide me how to implement this extension?
I'm a beginner (obviously) and I don't really know what should be the "form_tag" action, where should I implement it and which class should implement the extended search...

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Are you using Rails 2.x or 3.x? Looks like 2.x, but if you're new, then you'll want to start on 3.x

Comment: Actually I'm using rails 3.2.3.. Am I using old syntax?

Comment: Yes, the `find(:all)` is old. you want `where` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, to just easily set off presuming you have a Symptom class similar to the Illness class(btw it would be most clean if you refactored the search functionality into a module and then include this module in both classes) then you can do:

```
class IllnessesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = Illness.search(params[:search]) + Symptom.search(params[:search])
    ...
  end
end
```

But maybe you would like to refactor the name of the controller, because now it is not anymore Illness specific. Also notice that we are here using two search queries instead of one so it is not optimal, but saves you the pain of sending a pure SQL query for two types of models at the same time.

Okay for the module. If you are not familiar with modules they might seem a little weird but they are little more than a piece of code that can be shared across classes to keep things DRY which is our case too. You can imagine including the module as taking the code from the module and evaluating it (courtesy of interpreted languages) in the context of the class which has the same result as if the module code was hard coded into the class itself. So the module looks like:

```
module Search
  def self.search(token)
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  end
end
```

And now any class, if it implements the find method(ActiveRecord API) can happily include this module and enjoy the search functionality like this:

```
require 'path/to/search'

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Search
end
```

That's it. Now if you need to tweak your search code, you change it in one place and it propagates to all the includers. You can also create modules inside modules which is sometimes used like this:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Search
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    #Stuff that gets done when the module is included (new validations, callbacks etc.)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    #Here you define stuff without the self. prefix
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    #Instance methods here
  end
end
```

But some of it is convention that is defined in ActiveSupport::Concern so not everything will probably work in pure ruby. I encourage you to experiment with these things, they make ruby real fun. Oh, extend is very much like include, only, as I understand it, it kind of evaluates on the class level. So all instance methods of the included module would become class methods of the includer module if you follow me. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks. If I want to go for the clean solution you suggested, how should my search module look like? and what do you mean by including it in both classes?  (I'm just looking for high level explanation, this language is just so different than anything I'm familiar with...)

Comment: Give me a while. I will edit my post so that you can see it with all the markdown in place ;-)